Image Texture is Not Mapping Correctly (Mosaic Appearance)
I put my model into adobe's autorigging software and after it was rigged, I imported into Blender and tried to apply my image texture to the model but it gave it a mosaic appearance instead of wrapping the whole thing. I tried everything under the moon, unwrapping, smart uv, and different nodes but I have no clue how to fix. I think the texture is applying to very vertex group or bone but thats just a suspicion based on no knowledge besides eyes. I'm attaching the nodes as it is given, not what I tried to do. Let me know what I can do.

It seems that you may not know how UV maps work, nor how UV unwrapping is meant to be done. It’s not a “push the make proper UV maps button” type thing. I strongly recommend you look into it. Can almost guarantee the present problem is that the UV map was scrambled.

Do you still have the original unrigged model with proper UVs?

Yes, I have the original model with the texture that has proper UV application, can you recommend tutorials?

First off, there are hundreds. Do some research, bro. Second off, was this 3D scanned?
